# problems with full-text search in postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have the next table, and data:

```
/* script for people table, with field tsvector and gin */

CREATE TABLE public.people (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  lastname VARCHAR(30),
  complete TSVECTOR
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX idx_complete ON public.people
  USING gin (complete);

/* data for people table */

INSERT INTO public.people ("id", "name", "lastname", "complete")
VALUES 
  (1, 'MICHAEL', 'BRYANT BRYANT', '''bryant'':2,3 ''michael'':1'),
  (2, 'HENRY STEVEN', 'BUSH TIESSEN', '''bush'':3 ''henri'':1 ''steven'':2 ''tiessen'':4'),
  (3, 'WILLINGTON STEVEN', 'STEPHENS FLINN', '''flinn'':4 ''stephen'':3 ''steven'':2 ''willington'':1'),
  (4, 'BRET', 'MARTINEZ AROCH', '''aroch'':3 ''bret'':1 ''martinez'':2'),
  (5, 'TERENCE BERT', 'CAVALIERE ENRON', '''bert'':2 ''cavalier'':3 ''terenc'':1');
```

I need retrieve the names and lastnames, according the `tsvector` field.  Actually I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE complete @@ to_tsquery('WILLINGTON & FLINN');
```

And the result is right (the third record).  BUT if I try with

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE complete @@ to_tsquery('STEVEN & FLINN');
/* the same record! */
```

I don't have results.  Why?  What can I do?

Comment: Which version are you using? Did a quick run on sqlfiddle but could not reproduce: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2439d3/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same language to search your table as the values in your field 'complete' where inserted.

Check the result of that query compared english and german:

```
select * ,
to_tsvector('english', concat_ws(' ', name, lastname )) as english,
to_tsvector('german', concat_ws(' ', name, lastname )) as german
from public.people
```

so that should work for you :

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE complete @@ to_tsquery('english','STEVEN & FLINN');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a text search configuration where either `STEVEN` or `FLINN` are modified by stemming.

I can reproduce this here:

```
test=> SHOW default_text_search_config;
 default_text_search_config 
----------------------------
 pg_catalog.german
(1 row)

test=> SELECT complete FROM public.people WHERE id = 3;
                    complete                     
-------------------------------------------------
 'flinn':4 'stephen':3 'steven':2 'willington':1
(1 row)

test=> SELECT * FROM ts_debug('STEVEN & FLINN');
   alias   |   description   | token  | dictionaries  | dictionary  | lexemes 
-----------+-----------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | STEVEN | {german_stem} | german_stem | {stev}
 blank     | Space symbols   |        | {}            |             | 
 blank     | Space symbols   | &      | {}            |             | 
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | FLINN  | {german_stem} | german_stem | {flinn}
(4 rows)

test=> SELECT * FROM public.people
       WHERE complete @@ to_tsquery('STEVEN & FLINN');
 id | name | lastname | complete 
----+------+----------+----------
(0 rows)
```

So you see, the German Snowball dictionary stems `STEVEN` to `stev`.

Since `complete` contains the unstemmed version `steven`, no match is found.

You should use the same text search configuration when you populate `complete` and in the query.